# Why is InitializeComponent(); inaccessible due to its protection level?

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

So here's the current code that I have and I'm getting the error:

> 'SampleWindows.BaseWindow.InitializeComponent()' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122)

Any help?

```
using System;

namespace SampleWindows
{
    public class Form1 : BaseWindow
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RoundedCorners(this.Height, this.Width);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it wpf or silverlight?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I'm sorry. I'm just a newbie, I don't think I know what those mean.

Comment: @GrantWinney: I'm making a sample window that has rounded corners. Sorry if I find it hard to understand.

Comment: @Midnight You mean winform?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: I guess its a wpf application, can you please check your  Build Action on the properties of the app.xmal  set to ApplicationDefinition

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I'm using SharpDevelop and I can't seem to find that?

Comment: Oh come on guys. He's obviously a newbie. When i was hired I couldn't "mark as startup project". There's a learning curve. Isn't it funny to you when non-programmers think we know everything about every program? This is the same thing.

Comment: @MillieSmith Just read the converstations here, i agree with your point. But he should have posted all the details in the initial question.

Comment: You're missing a "public" somewhere in front of class or the declaration of InitializeComponent or something. Right click on InitializeComponent and hit "Go To Definition" and check if it is marked public.

Comment: @Sajeetharan He doesn't know what he's doing yet. He's not experienced enough to post all the data without getting help.

Comment: @GrantWinney it's not Winforms. Afaik Winforms doesn't have a BaseWindow. Valid point on the private-ness of InitializeComponent.

Comment: @GrantWinney Either you edited your comment, or I didn't fully read the last part. I agree with Form1 looking like Winforms. Since he's a beginner I'm assuming he's sticking to old tricks and calling everything Form. If he were extending the wrong base class he'd probably be asking a question about that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It seems that the option to 'Goto Definition' isn't available for InitializeComponent for some reason. Form1, BaseWindow, etc. are Classes (.cs). Sorry if I haven't cleared that up.

Comment: @Midnight can you upload all of your code and link to it here?

Comment: Hey guys, for some reason. I understood what marking it to public means and it now seems to work without errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's because InitializeComponent is probably marked 'private' inside BaseWindow but here in your class Form1 you are trying to use it.  You cannot use methods/class members from a base class that have been marked private. Try marking it 'protected'.